# How to prove that the evaluation map is a ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

This is a **really easy** question, but I'm stuck in the logic of it...

> Let $F$ be an integral domain and $F[x]$ its polynomial ring. Let $a\in F$ fixed, define $\phi: F[x]\to F$ as $\phi(p(x))=p(a)$. Prove that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

I daresay this is trivial and follows from its own definition... but I'm not sure. I'm seeing it as a "change of variable" or something like that. So I ask... what would be the argument? Thanks a lot, I'm sorry for this easy one.

Comment: Just check that it satisfies the properties of a homomorphism. It's not clear to me what you're struggling with.

Comment: Hi Michael. See the answer below, maybe you get the point I'm stuck with. Thanks.

Comment: The operations on $F[x]$ are designed so that the map $p[x]\mapsto \sum_{k} \alpha_k a^k$ is a homomorphism of rings. It would not work if we had  the definition say:$(\sum \alpha_k x^k) \cdot (\sum_k \beta_k x^k) = \sum_k \alpha_k \beta_k x^k$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a modified version of a proof I found on an old website, the link to which seems to have expired:

Let $f(x) = a_nx^n + \ldots + a_0x^0$, and $g(x) = b_nx^n+ \ldots + b_0x^0$, where the $a_i,b_i ∈ \mathbb F$, and let $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}$ be the field element we wish to evaluate the polynomials on. (We'll also allow leading coefficients to be zero in order to make it easier to add $f$ and $g$ formally.) We then check the ring homomorphism conditions:

- We have:
  $$\begin{aligned}
  \phi(f+g) &=\phi((a_n+b_n)x^n + \ldots + (a_0 + b_0)x^0) \\
  &= (a_n + b_n)\alpha^n + \ldots + (a_0 + b_0)\alpha^0 \\
  &= (a_n\alpha^n + \ldots + a_0\alpha^0) + (b_n\alpha^n + \ldots + b_0\alpha^0) \\
  &=\phi(f) + \phi(g)
  \end{aligned}$$
  So $\phi$ is an additive group homomorphism.
- Since we know that $\phi$ is an additive homomorphism, we only need to check that it is multiplicative on monomials. But that's easy:
  $$\phi((ax^n)(bx^m))=\phi(abx^{n+m}) = ab\alpha^{n+m}=\phi(ax^n)\phi(bx^m)$$

Comment: Great! you got the spirit of the question. Thank you very much for the answer, and the reference.

Comment: [Why we only need to check it's multiplicative on monomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825249/proving-that-evaluation-map-is-ring-homomorphism)

Answer (score 5):

(This is too long for a comment, but may be useful for someone like me who has learned the universal property of polynomial rings from a commutative algebra course but wants examples of how to understand how to apply it in concrete situations like the one OP has above.)

If you assume the [universal property of polynomial rings](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Polynomial_Ring) as given (which you ***shouldn't***, since it's basically just a more general version of the result you want to show, i.e. this accept should ***not*** be accepted), then the result you want follows by choosing the right data to input into the result.

> Let $R,S$ be commutative and unitary rings. Let $\langle s_j \rangle_{j \in J}$ be an indexed family of elements of $S$. Let $\psi: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Then there exists a **unique** ring homomorphism $$\phi: R[\{X_j: j \in J \}] \to S $$ such that:
>
> 1. $\forall r \in R$, one has that $\phi(r) = \psi(r)$, i.e. $\phi$ extends $\psi$,
> 2. $\forall j \in J$, one has that $\phi(X_j) = s_j$.

A fairly rigorous proof of this result is given [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Polynomial_Ring), although the notation on [the page explaining the properties of $\phi$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Polynomial_Evaluation_Homomorphism) is inconsistent with the notation on the original page, hence why I re-wrote the result in its entirely so that it is more easily understandable.

- Note the integral domain $F$ is by assumption a commutative and unitary ring. Therefore, we can take both $R = F$ and $S = F$.
- Take $J$ to be any one-element set, and let $s:= s_1 = a \in S = F$.
- It follows also from this that $R[\{X_j: j \in J \}] = F[X_1] =: F[X]$.
- Finally, let the ring homomorphism $\psi: R \to S$ just be $Id_F: F \to F$, the identity on $F$.

Then in this special case, the above result says that:

> There exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi: F[X] \to F$ such that:
>
> 1. $\forall x \in F$, one has that $\phi(x) = x$.
> 2. Moreover, $\phi(X) = a$.

It follows from this, as @orangeskid noted in a comment on the original post, that $\phi(p) = "p(a)"$ for all polynomials $p \in F[X]$.

While this approach is certainly more abstract, it does have at least the benefit that we do not need to assume a priori that polynomials do in fact form an algebra of functions on $F$, instead we can *prove* that such an identification of polynomials with an algebra of functions on $F$ is valid.