# $\phi(a)=a$ and $\phi(x)=\alpha$ (solution attempt)

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $L$ extension of field $K$ and $\alpha \in L$.

$\phi : K[x]\rightarrow L $ for
$\phi(a)=a$ ,$\forall a \in K$ and
$\phi(x)=\alpha.$

a)  Prove $\phi$ is homomorphism of ring

Hi, a few hours ago I asked for help to interpret the text of the question, now I come here to bring up doubts about an attempt to demonstrate item a).

From what I understand this function is doing two things simultaneously to $\phi(a)$ e $\phi(x)$.

Homomorphism:

(+) There are 3 possibilities:

(1)

$\phi(a+b)$, $a,b \in K$ $\rightarrow$ $\exists c \in K \rightarrow c=a+b$

$\phi(c)=c=a+b=\phi(a)+\phi(b)$

(2)

$\phi(a+x)$, $a \in K x \notin K$. Let $z=a+x$ we will have 2 possibility:

$z \in K$ or $z \notin K$.

For $z \in K$, $\phi(z)=z=a+x=\phi(a)+x$.

For $z \notin K$ , $\phi(z)=\alpha$.

Both possibilities go wrong because what we want $\phi(a+x)=\phi(a)+\phi(x)=a+\alpha$

(3)

$\phi(x+y)$, $x,y \notin K$ Applying the same method as above I arrive at. $\phi(z)$=x+y or $\phi(z)=\alpha$.

(.) There are 3 possibilities:

(4) $\phi(ab)$, $a,b \in K$ $\rightarrow \exists c \in K \rightarrow c=ab$,then $\phi(c)=c=ab=\phi(a)\phi(b)$

(5)

$\phi(ax),a \in K$ $x \notin K$ , K is field $ax \in K$  $\rightarrow \exists c \in K \rightarrow c=ax$,then $\phi(c)=c=ax=\phi(a)x$.What is different from $\phi(ax)=\phi(a)\phi(x)=a\alpha$

(6)

$\phi(xy), x,y \notin K$. Let $z=xy \rightarrow \phi(z)$ have 2 possibilite : $z \in K$ or $z \notin K$.

For $z \in K$:

$\phi(z)=z=xy$

For $z \notin K$.

$\phi(z)=\alpha$

both are different from $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)=\alpha^2$

My doubts are what I'm leaving to consider or use? is there an easier proof than simply separating in by your chances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the evaluation homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$. You can find a short proof here: [How to prove that the evaluation map is a ring homomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935877/how-to-prove-that-the-evaluation-map-is-a-ring-homomorphism)

I am not sure you are really understanding the definition of a polynomial ring. It has no sense to write something like $x \notin K$ since $x$ in this context is just a formal symbol, it doesn't represent an element of the ring. What you have to show is that given two polynomials $f = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x_{n-1} + \dots + a_0$, $g = b^m x^m + b_{m-1} x_{m-1} + \dots + b_0$ then $\phi(f) \phi(g) = \phi (fg)$ and $\phi(f) + \phi(g) = \phi (f+g)$.

As the link shows, for the product case it is sufficient to prove it for monomials. I suggest you reread your definition of a polynomial ring, so you get a feel for what they are in a more algebraic (rather than analytical) context.

About the evaluation homomorphism: As it name says, it is an "evaluation". You have probably studied polynomials "as functions" in analysis, for example $f(x) = x^2$, you give it a real number and it gives another real number.

In algebra, polynomials are defined "formally": not as functions but as a sum of (finite) terms of the form $a_n x^n$. The evaluation homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$ is equivalent to substituting every appearance of $x$ with the associated element (in this case $\alpha$) and calculating the result.

This turns out to be very useful, for example we can define the set of polynomials that have $\alpha$ as a root, as the kernel of the homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$. We can then apply the powerful theorems we have for homomorphisms to polynomial rings: for example, we know that the set of all polynomials that have $\alpha$ as root is an ideal (since the kernel of a ring homomorphism is always an ideal).

The importance of the evaluation homomorphism is that it connects both aspects of the polynomial: the fact that it can be viewed as a function with some special points (the root) or it can be viewed formally.

Comment: So what exactly does $\phi(a)=a$ mean? @zanzag

Comment: @AlexandreGod I have added some extra information about the evaluation homomorphism. That part just means that the evaluation leaves the coefficients of every term fixed, as you would do if you just "substituted" every appearance of the symbol $x$ by $\alpha$.